# Manually create Tokens in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.1 I used something like:

```
function enable(TokenRepositoryInterface $tokens)
{
    // (...)
    $token = $tokens->create($user);
    Mail::send('emails.enabled', ['user' => $user, 'email' => $user->email, 'token' => $token], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Welcome to ..., ' . $user->name . '!');
    });
    // (...)
}
```

to manually send a password-set token, after sign up (by abusing Laravels own password-reset tokens). However the `TokenRepositoryInterface` repository interface seems to be gone in Laravel 5.2.

**Is there any way to manually create a password-reset token in Laravel 5.2 or do I need to manually implement that token handling for sign ups?**

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11555#issuecomment-167444079

Comment: Thank you @CharlotteDunois. I wasn't aware this was an issue, just thought this is related to their changes to their Authentication&Authorization components.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a token using a passport in your laravel application

```
$user->createToken('Client Token')->accessToken;
```